Hyperledger fabric system channel orderers update error 1.4
Im trying to update the system channel in order to add a new Orderer.
The protobuf is signed by the organization admin and I see that it gets to the Orderer that I send the transaction, but I can not see any other related logs on the other 2 channels of the organization.
I can provide more info if needed, thank you.
When the transaction is rejected, this is what I see on the orderer log.
2024-04-16 09:34:56.349 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 10429ee3 0xc001d84cd0 principal evaluation succeeds for identity 0
2024-04-16 09:34:56.349 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 10429ee4 0xc001d84cd0 gate 1713260096348359729 evaluation succeeds
2024-04-16 09:34:56.349 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 10429ee5 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Orderer/OrgMSP/Writers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.349 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 10429ee6 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/OrgMSP/Writers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.349 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 10429ee7 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.349 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 10429ee8 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.349 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 10429ee9 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Writers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.349 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 10429eea == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.350 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429eeb Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel
2024-04-16 09:34:56.350 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429eec Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel
2024-04-16 09:34:56.350 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429eed Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel/Consortiums
2024-04-16 09:34:56.350 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429eee Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel/Consortiums/OrgConsortium
2024-04-16 09:34:56.350 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429eef Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel/Consortiums/OrgConsortium/OrgMSP
2024-04-16 09:34:56.350 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429ef0 Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/Consortiums/OrgConsortium/OrgMSP/MSP
2024-04-16 09:34:56.350 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429ef1 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Consortiums/OrgConsortium/OrgMSP/Admins
2024-04-16 09:34:56.350 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429ef2 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Consortiums/OrgConsortium/OrgMSP/Readers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.350 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429ef3 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Consortiums/OrgConsortium/OrgMSP/Writers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.350 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429ef4 Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/Consortiums/OrgConsortium/ChannelCreationPolicy
2024-04-16 09:34:56.351 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429ef5 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Consortiums/Admins
2024-04-16 09:34:56.351 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429ef6 Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel/Orderer
2024-04-16 09:34:56.351 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429ef7 Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel/Orderer/OrgMSP
2024-04-16 09:34:56.351 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429ef8 Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/OrgMSP/MSP
2024-04-16 09:34:56.351 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429ef9 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Orderer/OrgMSP/Admins
2024-04-16 09:34:56.351 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429efa Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Orderer/OrgMSP/Readers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.351 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429efb Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Orderer/OrgMSP/Writers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.351 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429efc Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/BatchSize
2024-04-16 09:34:56.351 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429efd Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/BatchTimeout
2024-04-16 09:34:56.352 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429efe Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/ChannelRestrictions
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429eff Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/Orderer/ConsensusType
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429f00 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Orderer/Readers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429f01 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429f02 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Orderer/Admins
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429f03 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Orderer/BlockValidation
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429f04 Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/BlockDataHashingStructure
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429f05 Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/HashingAlgorithm
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429f06 Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/OrdererAddresses
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429f07 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Admins
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429f08 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Readers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.353 UTC [common.configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 10429f09 Adding to config map: [Policy] /Channel/Writers
2024-04-16 09:34:56.354 UTC [common.configtx] verifyDeltaSet -> DEBU 10429f0a Processing change to key: [Policy] /Channel/Orderer/OrgMSP/Admins
2024-04-16 09:34:56.354 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 10429f0b [channel: Orgsystem] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.33.13.79:58208 because of error: error applying config update to existing channel 'Orgsystem': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: attempt to set key [Policy] /Channel/Orderer/OrgMSP/Admins to version 0, but key is at version 0
2024-04-16 09:34:56.354 UTC [orderer.common.server] func1 -> DEBU 10429f0c Closing Broadcast stream
2024-04-16 09:34:56.354 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10429f0d streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=172.33.13.79:58208 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=6.298844ms
2024-04-16 09:34:56.364 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 10429f0e Error reading from 172.33.13.79:58194: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2024-04-16 09:34:56.364 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 10429f0f transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2024-04-16 09:34:56.364 UTC [orderer.common.server] func1 -> DEBU 10429f10 Closing Deliver stream
2024-04-16 09:34:56.364 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 10429f12 transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
2024-04-16 09:34:56.364 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 10429f11 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=172.33.13.79:58194 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=23.411074ms

Edit:
I see that in the channel config there are versions specified:
            "Writers": {
              "mod_policy": "Admins",
              "policy": {
                "type": 3,
                "value": {
                  "rule": "ANY",
                  "sub_policy": "Writers"
                }
              },
              "version": "0"
            }

Do I need to update all those versions?
On the source code of the hyperledger fabric on the update.go of the configtx the method verifyDeltaSet there is the following validation:
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/common/configtx/update.go#L67
        if value.version() != existing.version()+1 {
            return errors.Errorf("attempt to set key %s to version %d, but key is at version %d", key, value.version(), existing.version())
        }

So, Is this version updated on the process of creating the pb file automatically? or is something that needs to be specified?
Thank you.
